# Optional parameters in Moya task

Tags: ios, swift, moya

I am using `Moya` and have a situation where some parameters of a request to an endpoint are not required, so the target looks like this:

```
case save(projectId: Int?, seconds: Int, description: String?)
```

Currently Moya's `requestParameters(parameters:encoding:)` method expects a dictionary of type `[String:Any]`.

Is there a workaround for this scenario? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You always send parameters though a dictionnary (that can be empty). You are asking how you can not insert a value in a dictionary when switch on your optional parameter (projectId or description)? Or are you asking if you can avoid specifying parameters? (Your seconds is not optional by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tigran jan if-let ov stugi ete nil chi, nor qic dict-i mej.

```
switch self {
case .save(projectId: let projectId, seconds: let seconds, description: let description): 
    var params: [String:Any] = ["seconds" : seconds] 
    if let projectId = projectId 
        params["projectId"] = projectId
    } 

    if let description = description {
        params["description"] = description
    }
    return .requestParameters(parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
}
```

Comment: Mersi, Artur jan. Chishtn asac, et lucum@ parz er, uxaki mtacum ei, vor karoxa aveli elegant tarberak exner. Amen depqum k@ndunem patasxant :)